# How to correctly add the rows from a table that were linked by an id to another table on MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, debugging, join

Suppose that the following query:

```
SELECT author, is_public, content
FROM dapp.messages WHERE is_public = '0'
```

gets the following table:

```
| author| is_public      | content            |
-----------------------------------------------
|  3240 |0               |Hello, I'm Bertha   |
|  4039 |0               |Hello, I'm Kristina |
|  4810 |0               |Hello, I'm April    |
```

Now, in this case, the numbers in the column `author` are linked to a row in another table called `credentials`, which means that:

`3240` is linked to this row in `credentials` table:

```
|   id  | first_name   | member_type   |
----------------------------------------
|  3240 |Bertha        | regular       |
```

`4039` is linked to this row in `credentials` table:

```
|   id  | first_name   | member_type   |
----------------------------------------
|  4039 |Kristina      | regular       |
```

`4810` is linked to this row in `credentials` table:

```
|   id  | first_name   | member_type   |
----------------------------------------
|  4039 |April         | regular       |
```

So, I would like to know a correct way of adding the `first name` column from `credentials` table to the table obtained by the first query in this post, ending up with an output like this:

```
| author| is_public      | content            | first_name   |
--------------------------------------------------------------
|  3240 |0               |Hello, I'm Bertha   |Bertha        |
|  4039 |0               |Hello, I'm Kristina |Kristina      |
|  4810 |0               |Hello, I'm April    |April         |
```

I thought that by trying the following query, I would get the desired output from above:

```
SELECT t1.*, t2.*
FROM (SELECT author, is_public, content
    FROM dapp.messages
    WHERE is_public = '0') t1
CROSS JOIN (SELECT first_name
    FROM dapp.credentials
    WHERE id IN (SELECT author FROM dapp.messages)) t2
```

But I ended up creating a monstrosity that threw this output:

```
| author| is_public      | content            | first_name   |
--------------------------------------------------------------
|  3240 |0               |Hello, I'm Bertha   |Bertha        |
|  3240 |0               |Hello, I'm Bertha   |Kristina      |
|  3240 |0               |Hello, I'm Bertha   |April         |
|  4039 |0               |Hello, I'm Kristina |Bertha        |
|  4039 |0               |Hello, I'm Kristina |Kristina      |
|  4039 |0               |Hello, I'm Kristina |April         |
|  4810 |0               |Hello, I'm April    |Bertha        |
|  4810 |0               |Hello, I'm April    |Kristina      |
|  4810 |0               |Hello, I'm April    |April         |
```

Which I didn't get at all, so I'm stuck.

Comment: You should spend some time studying joins https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/join.html

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code & example input; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. For SQL include DDL & tabular initialization code. For debug that includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. [ask] [Help] When you get a result you don't expect, pause your overall goal, chop to the 1st subexpression with unexpected result & say what you expected & why, justified by documentation. (Debugging fundamental.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure why you think you need a *cross* join here, it appears you need a simple inner join:

```
select m.author, m.is_public, m.content, c.first_name
from dapp.messages m 
join dapp.credentials c on c.id = m.author
where m.is_public = '0';
```

As you want a single column a *correlated subquery* is also a viable option:

```
  select m.author, m.is_public, m.content, 
    (select first_name from dapp.credentials c where c.id = m.author) as first_name
  from dapp.messages m 
  where m.is_public = '0';
```

Comment: 'why you think you need a cross join here' -because OP accepted such a solution in a previously asked question..

Comment: @P.Salmon ah I see, yes. That solution worked for that scenario though - OP a *cross join* produces a *cartesian product* and is rarely required, normal 1-1 joins simply use *[inner] join*

Comment: Thanks a lot! I will try my best to code better queries from now on :D